# How to count the number of first transactions of each user per day?

Tags: mysql

I have a table named `transactions` which contains all transactions. Something like this:

```
// transactions
+--------+-------------+---------+-------------+---------------------+
|  id    | business_id | user_id |   amount    |      created_at     |
+--------+-------------+---------+-------------+---------------------+
| 1      | 503         | 12      | 4500        | 2021-04-15 04:22:09 |
| 2      | 33          | 12      | 1200        | 2021-04-17 12:22:10 |
| 3      | 771         | 13      | 400         | 2021-04-18 13:02:18 |
| 4      | 86          | 14      | 7500        | 2021-04-18 16:07:12 | 
| 5      | 772         | 13      | 3400        | 2021-04-23 07:11:04 |
| 6      | 652         | 14      | 900         | 2021-04-24 10:35:08 |
| 7      | 567         | 15      | 1000        | 2021-04-24 14:55:11 |
+--------+-------------+---------+-------------+---------------------+
```

I need to count the number of users that have had their **first transaction per day**. So here is the expected result:

```
// The expected result
+------+-------+-------+--------------------------+
| year | month |  day  |  first_transactions_num  |
+------+-------+-------+--------------------------+
| 2021 | 04    | 15    | 1                        |
| 2021 | 04    | 18    | 2                        |
| 2021 | 04    | 24    | 1                        |
+------+-------+-------+--------------------------+
```

Any idea how can I do that?

---

Here's what I've tried:

```
SELECT year(created_at) year,
       month(created_at) month,
       day(created_at) day,
       count(1) num
FROM transactions
GROUP BY year, month, day
```

But **my query doesn't care about "the first transaction of each user".**

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "first transaction per day". Any user that has a transaction on any day will have a first transaction on that day, no? I see a 1 on the April 24th, but two users have a transaction on that day.

Answer (score 1):

You should aggregate on the results of this query:

```
SELECT MIN(created_at) created_at
FROM transactions
GROUP BY user_id
```

which returns the 1st transaction of each user.
So do it like this:

```
SELECT YEAR(created_at) year,
       MONTH(created_at) month,
       DAY(created_at) day,
       COUNT(*) num
FROM (
  SELECT MIN(created_at) created_at
  FROM transactions
  GROUP BY user_id
) t
GROUP BY year, month, day
```

Or better:

```
SELECT YEAR(created_at) year,
       MONTH(created_at) month,
       DAY(created_at) day,
       COUNT(*) num
FROM (
  SELECT DATE(MIN(created_at)) created_at
  FROM transactions
  GROUP BY user_id
) t
GROUP BY created_at
```

Or if your version of MySql is 8.0+ use `COUNT()` window function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       YEAR(MIN(created_at)) year,
       MONTH(MIN(created_at)) month,
       DAY(MIN(created_at)) day,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY DATE(MIN(created_at))) num
FROM transactions
GROUP BY user_id
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=85f23ec9369cba0c7d26e4927ed10ed0).

Comment: ..that moment when you understand the Question by reading the Answer ;)

Comment: Your answer is completely correct, upvote .. But sadly I cannot merge your query structure in the query I have in reality ... please take a look at [this](https://gist.github.com/sajadshafizadeh/fc7af60ed1f9c7d7b216f2f3164a0a4a), can you add your query to mine as a new item in the `select` statemtnt? (noted that, MySQL 8.0+ is supported)

Comment: @stack no, this is a different requirement in which you join other tables and you expect different results.